# Draw simple 3D graphs and shapes in vector format

Tags: windows, 3d, graphs, plotting

As an example, I want to produce the figure below. I drew this figure painfully in Powerpoint and want to find a better/more efficient way of doing this. Unfortunately, Powerpoint is the best solution I've found so far. (By the way this here is merely a rasterized screenshot of the vector image in PDF.)

This is for high-school 3D geometry and all I need to draw are simple and clear points, lines, planes, vectors.

[image]

Essential requirements:

1. **Vector format** - PDF preferred, but any format that can be converted to PDF with full vector format preserved is good as well (SVG, AI, etc.)
2. **Easy to use.** For example, Geogebra is easy to use -- I can just quickly enter "Plane: x=1", "Point: (1,0,0)", "Point: (1,1,1)", and "Point: (1,3,1)" and they'll be plotted.
3. Colors and size/thickness of points, lines, and planes are **customizable**, like in Powerpoint/Illustrator.

Nice to have:

4. The labels are customizable (but if not, no big deal because I can always edit them into the PDF).
5. Free.
6. Lightweight.

Some of the programs I've tried so far are GNU Octave, Mathmod, Geogebra, Mathematica, Matlab, Microsoft Math, but none have been any better/quicker than simply drawing figures "by hand" in Powerpoint (or Illustrator or Inkscape).

(Though it is very possible that I've just been stupid and couldn't figure out how to use those. If someone could show me how I could, for example, produce the above figure easily in any of the aforementioned programs, I'd be very grateful too.)

If it matters, I use Windows 10.

Comment: Using Inkscape will give you more options for drawing. However, to define programatically the plot you need, the best solution is programming. Here, an example of what can be done in R: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/3-r-animated-cube/

Comment: Certainly overkill, if you don't have Blender power already: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/export_svg.html

Comment: It would be so cool if Geogebra allowed you to project a 3D model and export it as SVG... unfortunately it does not seem to have that feature :-/

Answer (score 1):

I would ask in a different in the Math forum.

Here you have a similar question with lots of suggestions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/recommended-free-software-to-plot-points-in-3d

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the [python](https://www.python.org/) [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) library & specifically at mplot3d for which there is a tutorial with samples [here](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html).

To address your requirements:

- The output must also be in vector format: Possible output formats include png, **eps**, jpg, **pdf**, pgf, **svg**, **svgz** - *so vectors are covered*.
- Colours, lines & points easily adjusted: not so easy but can be done.
- Free: Python & matplotlib are Free, Gratis & Open Source.
- Lightweight: The latest python windows installer is 26 MB
- Windows 10: Yes & OS-X & Linux

The down side is that this is an actual plotting library rather than a drawing one.

Comment: For the record, EPS is a vector format too.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - yes it is but the range of software that can read it is limited enough that I did not consider it worth boldening - done now.